# Braintree transaction status android, how to check if declined?

Tags: android, http, response, payment-gateway, braintree

I try to figure out how to check for transaction status in my android app using the Braintree payment gateway.

I have read their documentations, there are decline codes like 2001 if there are insufficient funds. But this refers to the server side only, I have implemented this as:

```
...
$nonce = $_POST["payment_method_nonce"];
$amount = $_POST["amount"];

$result = Braintree_Transaction::sale(array(
  'amount' => $amount,
  'paymentMethodNonce' => $nonce
));


if ($result->success) {
    echo("Success! Transaction ID: " . $result->transaction->id);
} else if ($result->transaction->status) {
    echo("Error: " . $result->message);
    echo("<br/>");
    echo("Code: " . $result->transaction->processorResponseCode);
} 

...
```

But as I check for the payment nonce, there is no way to get the response back, I have tried via reading headers, but there I get nothing from what I echo out:

android implementation:

```
void postNonceToServer(String nonce) {

        //set a boolean to veryfy transaction status, then send files in onResume (error if trying in onActivityResult)
        transactionDone = true;

        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        params.put("payment_method_nonce", nonce);
        params.put("amount", total);
        client.post("http://edmondvarga.com/laborator/brt_server/payment-methods.php", params,
                new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(int i, Header[] headers, byte[] bytes) {

                        HashMap<String, String> result = new HashMap<String, String>(headers.length);
                        for (Header header : headers) {
                            result.put(header.getName(), header.getValue());
                            Log.i("header", "name/value: " + header.getName() + " " + header.getValue() + " or " + header.getName().toString() + " " + header.getValue().toString());
                        }


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(int i, Header[] headers, byte[] bytes, Throwable throwable) {
                        Log.i("Nonce", "sending nonce failed!");
                    }

                }
        );
    }
```

So how could I verify the status of the transaction before I am serving my client?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a developer at Braintree. In general, the nonce will not contain processor verification information, because these verifications are not run until you attempt to create a transaction using the nonce (with your server-side call).

If you are using our drop-in integration, you can choose to run these verifications before creating the nonce by [enabling verifications in the control panel](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/control-panel/vault/card-verification#enabling-card-verification). In this case, the nonce creation will only succeed if the verifications pass.

Answer (score 0):

`PaymentMetodNonce` is an random integer number while you processing the transaction from the client side. You need a Braintree token for the transaction. You need to create the customer_id. Using the customer_id and paymentmethodnonce you can generate the `braintree token`. Follow this link:
  [Correct way to link PayPal Accounts to vault with Braintree DropUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079792/correct-way-to-link-paypal-accounts-to-vault-with-braintree-dropui/31327000#31327000)