# Correct way to link PayPal Accounts to vault with Braintree DropUI

Tags: paypal, braintree

I have the following controller:

```
class PaymentsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:new]

    def new
        gon.client_token = generate_client_token
    end

    def create
        @result = Braintree::Transaction.sale(
                            amount: 60,
                            payment_method_nonce: params[:payment_method_nonce])
        if @result.success?
            puts @result.transaction.payment_instrument_type
            flash[:notice] = 'Yes, transaction completed'
        else
            flash[:alert] = "Something went wrong while processing your transaction. Please try again!"
      gon.client_token = generate_client_token
            render :new
        end
    end

    private

    def generate_client_token
        Braintree::ClientToken.generate(customer_id: current_user.braintree_customer_id)
    end
end
```

With the above code, I was testing with linking a paypal account to the vault for a specific customer. However It won't link. I checked the documentation reference it seems to me it shouldn't be any extra tweak.

Any hint?

Comment: Hey Chris; I'm on the Pay with PayPal team at Braintree.  Would you mind posting both the code you used to initialize the Dropin UI as well as what version of braintree.js you are using?  I can help get you sorted out from there.

Answer (score 0):

I worked on the braintree for api development using python/javascript. You need to create the `braintree token` for the transaction.If you have the customer_id you can generate the braintree token. You can follow this code to create the token:

```
def checkout(request):
    api_token = request.session['token']
    nonce = request.POST['payment_method_nonce']
    customer = Customer.objects.get(user=request.user)
    # With this the PaymentMethod will be associated with the Customer
    result = braintree.PaymentMethod.create({
        "customer_id": customer.customer_id,
        "payment_method_nonce": nonce
    })
    token = result.payment_method.token
    print token
    # you the BT token to charge the user
    result = braintree.Transaction.sale({
        "amount": 10,
        "payment_method_token": token,
        "options": {'submit_for_settlement': True}
    })
    print result.transaction.id
```